# Fetch distinct data from Core data alongwith descending order?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I creating chat app in which i save data in core data. I using following entity,

[image]

I want to fetch data all unique `customerno` and that data will be descending order of `messagedate` also contain latest `messagetext` which send from other `cmid`. I want to show list *like facebook chat message list and smiler view*. 
I trying following code ,

```
-(NSArray *)getAllInstanceMessages{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest * req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"IMDetails" inManagedObjectContext:theManageContext];
    [req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cmid=%@", theCmID]];
    NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
    [req setEntity:entity];
    [req setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [req setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [req setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"customerno"]]];
    [req setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"messagedate" ascending:NO]]];
    NSArray *result = [theManageContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%s, %@", __FUNCTION__, [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}
```

the above code given my following output,

```
Printing description of result:
<_PFArray 0xa3cda70>(
{
    customerno = CN00001;
    customerno = CN00002;
    customerno = CN00003;
}
)
```

I want complete data along with this unique numbers, i mean array of dictionary/ManagedObject containing unique data suppose in above CN0001 number but it doesn't contain other attributes values.

what i do wrong in code?

Answer (score 1):

According to the NSFetchRequest Class Reference documentation for the setPropertiesToFetch method: "This value is only used if resultType is set to NSDictionaryResultType."

Answer (score 0):

you need to set all attribute of table which you want to get in setPropertiesToFetch. Like

```
[req setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"customerno"],[entityProperties objectForKey:@"messagetext"],nil]];
```

This will return NSDictionary with both value.

Comment: your suggestion i tried before asking this question. The above line not impacting on uniqueness. Your messages rarely unique so above line give me result of all data of same patient which is i won't that.

Comment: above result i got using this [req setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"customerno"],
                           [entityProperties objectForKey:@"messagetext"],nil]];

Comment: after saw resulte set, one thing is clear your table hold all messageText data.

Comment: Yup. That i don't want. I want unique customerno with latest message record.

Comment: in that scenario, there is to solution 1: apply normlization in table or make two fetch statement , first fetch all unique user then messagetext in messageDate order.